# Two different groupping in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I have a table of places:

```
table place:
id INT,
name VARCHAR(255)
```

and a table to count visits to each place in each day:

```
table place_visit:
place_id INT,
date DATE,
count INT
```

Now I would like to fetch in one statement: place.id, place.name, SUM of today's visit count, and SUM of overall visit count (from all days).

Is this possible? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried at least something. Post whatever progress you've made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, SUM(IF(CURDATE() = pv.date, pv.count, 0)) todayCnt, 
       SUM(pv.count) allCnt
FROM place p 
INNER JOIN place_visit pv ON p.id = pv.place_id 
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted! I didn't even know that there can be IF statement in function! I've got so much to learn. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: while this will work, `LEFT JOIN` is much better than `INNER JOIN` to be used in this case since there are possibilities that a certain `ID` doesn't have a record on table `place_visit` on such day. `:D`

Comment: And CASE conforms to standard SQL

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. We can use both whichever we want

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = CURDATE() THEN b.count ELSE 0 END) dayVisit,
        SUM(b.count) overAllVisit
FROM    place a
        LEFT JOIN place_visit b
            ON a.ID = b.place_id
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e796f/2)